# How do you use coordinates to find location on map android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, reverse-geocoding

I am building a map in Java using Google Api Services. Currently my map takes in an address then finds and marks the location on my map. I would like it to be able to take in coordinates and find the location of those coordinates and mark that as well but havent had any luck finding documentation showing me how to do so. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks :)

Here is an image of My map to give some sort of visualization
!https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv3Y5.jpg

I need it to take in Lat/Long from my search bar and locate/mark area on map. This is my code so far for my Map Application

```
package net.androidbootcamp.mymapdemo;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by Micha on 3/1/2018.
 */

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Map is Ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: Map is Ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            init();
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;


    //Widget
    private EditText mSearchText;
    private ImageView mGps;

    //Variables
    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        getLocationPermission();
        mSearchText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        mGps = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_gps);

    }

    private void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: initializing");

        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textViewv, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                    //Execute method for searching
                    geoLocate();

                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onClick: clicked gps icon");
                getDeviceLocation();
            }
        });

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG,"geoLocate: geolocating");
        String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"geoLocate: IOException:" + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);

            Log.d(TAG,"geoLocate: found a location: " + address.toString());
            //Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),address.getLongitude()),DEFAULT_ZOOM, address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG,"getDeviceLocation: getting the devices current location");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionsGranted){
                Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG,"onComplete: found location!");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM,"My Location");
                        }else {
                            Log.d(TAG,"onComplete: current location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title){
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,zoom));
        if (!title.equals("My Location")){
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(title)
                    .draggable(true);
            mMap.addMarker(options);
        }
        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG,"initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    //Checks permissions
    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG,"getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                initMap();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");

        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG,"onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted");
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    //Initialize map
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }



    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the nature of the input coordinates?  Are they latitude/longitude, or something else?  Can you share the relevant code with us?

Comment: you want only  to mark place or  want to get info of place too using coordinates?

Comment: My coordinates would be latitude/longitude that the user would enter in a search bar and my map would locate that position and mark it

Comment: Then simply add Marker on that position  by taking that coordinates. whats the issue?

Comment: The problem I'm facing is when I enter an address like city state etc I'm fine, but if I enter a lat/long in my search box at the top it doesn't work. This is a photo taken of me entering lat/long for Los Angeles California and it is giving me Pittsburgh, PA !https://imgur.com/a/3JWpK

Comment: Check these links 1) https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete.  2) http://www.viralandroid.com/2016/04/google-maps-android-api-adding-search-bar-part-3.html

Comment: same question and code try with this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145015/not-getting-searched-place-in-maps/49145572#49145572

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Wrong method in case of searching against coordinates.

Use this for coordinates:

```
getFromLocation(double latitude, double longitude, int maxResults)
```

and us this when you have address:

```
getFromLocationName(String locationName, int maxResults)
```

Note one more thing, these above methods can return more than one addresses  and you are using 1st one from return List.

```
Address address = list.get(0);
```

Obviously, you can't be sure Address at index 0 will be desired Address and even setting `maxResults=1` is not a guarantee that you will get desired Address. So you have two options either show all return addresses on map or define your criteria which address type you want to show i.e, Restaurant,Hospital and soon....

Comment: So I would need to do a simple if statement saying if searchstring contains double split by "," then use getFromLocation       else getFromLocationName?

Comment: No, address could contain comma. Simplicity check for digits. is string contain only digits and comma? something like this

Comment: Zaid, Thank You so much! It works great how do I rate your comment on here im still new to StackOverflow

Comment: Never mind my last question i figured it out. I didnt see the checkmark. Anyways thank you again. :)